# How do I set up a nested, mutable database with key/subkey pairings?

Tags: python, database, dictionary, key-value

I am using keys and sub-keys for a nested database. I want the database to hold all of the values from all key/sub-key combinations. I thought to use dictionaries because they are mutable. However, the dictionary "flattens" and ignores the subkey. The script appears to hold only the last subkey value, ignoring the other unique sub-keys. Dictionary should hold: {Stuff} {Different Stuff} and {Something Completely Different}. but it only returns the last key/subkey pairing, "something completely different."

```
  [key1][subkey1] = {"Stuff"}
  [key1][subkey2] = {"Different stuff"}
  [key1][subkey3] = {"Something Completely Different"}
```

Structure I want using pseudocode:
Here is the code I tried. I am not sure if the dictionary only holds the last primary key/subkey pairing, or whether my print structure doesn't show the full dictionary. The dictionary only holds "Something Completely Different."

```
    myNestedDict = dict()
    myNestedDict = {"key1": {"subkey1": {'data': "Stuff"}}}
    myNestedDict = {"key1": {"subkey2": {'data': "Different stuff"}}}
    myNestedDict = {"key1": {"subkey3": {'data': "Something Completely Different"}}}
    for key, value in myNestedDict.items():
        for subkey, subvalue in myNestedDict[key].items():
            print(key, " ", subkey, " ", subvalue)
```

Comment: You aren't just assigning key/subkeys... you're completely reassigning the entire `myNestedDict` variable in each statement.  **Of course** you aren't retaining the previous contents...

Comment: How do I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pydantic` and `deep_update`:

```
# pip install pydantic
from pydantic.v1.utils import deep_update

myNestedDict = dict()
myNestedDict = deep_update(myNestedDict, {"key1": {"subkey1": {'data': "Stuff"}}})
myNestedDict = deep_update(myNestedDict, {"key1": {"subkey2": {'data': "Different stuff"}}})
myNestedDict = deep_update(myNestedDict, {"key1": {"subkey3": {'data': "Something Completely Different"}}})
```

Output:

```
>>> myNestedDict
{'key1': {'subkey1': {'data': 'Stuff'},
  'subkey2': {'data': 'Different stuff'},
  'subkey3': {'data': 'Something Completely Different'}}}
```

Comment: This was the best of the three proposed solutions. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

John Gordan is right, you're reassigning myNestedDict each time you try to add a subkey. To add keys to a dictionary in python, do something more like:

```
myNestedDict["key1"] = {"subkey1": {'data': "Stuff"}}
```

This adds the key: "key1" with the value assigned to it: the nested dictionary: {"subkey1": {'data': "Stuff"}}.

Edit: here's a relevant GeeksForGeeks page you may find helpful: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary/

Answer (score 1):

Assign the variable name `myNestedDict` **only once**:

```
myNestedDict = {"key1": {"subkey1": {'data': "Stuff"}}}
```

Then assign **additional keys** in the dict:

```
myNestedDict["key1"]["subkey2"] = {'data': "Different stuff"}
myNestedDict["key1"]["subkey3"] = {'data': "Something Completely Different"}
```